# How to prevent using multiple else if statement in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, if-statement

I have this script that walks through my page and looks for any tooltip to fill with the right ingredient.
But I would like to know if there is a way to optimize it as it goes like this:

```
var indiv = document.getElementById("ingredients");
var s = indiv.getElementsByTagName("SPAN"); 
var i;
    
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var ss = s[i].parentElement.textContent;
      
  var ingredient1 = ss.includes("test1");
  var ingredient2 = ss.includes("test2");
 
  if (ingredient1) {
    s[i].textContent = "this is the number 1 ingredient";
  } else if (ingredient2) {
    s[i].textContent = "this is the number 2 ingredien";
  } else {
    s[i].textContent = "unknown ingredient!";
  }
}
```

And it keeps going with `else if` (ingredient 3), `else if` (ingredient 4), etc.
I know that in Python there is a dictionary to use, but I can't find a good way to do that in JS.

Here is a snippet of my HTML if that helps:

```
<div id="ingredients">
    <div class="tooltiping bio" style="color: black;">Citrus Limon Fruit Water,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping bio" style="color: black;"> Hamamelis Virginiana Water,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping bio" style="color: black;"> Glycerin,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

So the purpose of the script is to change the unknown value in `<span>` to the right value.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of you html as well?

Comment: `I know that in Python there is a dictionnary to use but I can't find a good way to do that in JS` JS has objects.

Comment: What do you mean with optimizing it? Better performance, better readability or something else?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes I edited the post with a part of my html

Comment: @Kielstra I would like better performance is it is a really really long script I think to execute and my Prestashop website doesn't like that very much ^^

Comment: Why do you render empty tooltips and update them in js afterwards? Why don't you just render them together with your html?

Comment: @DenisHénon are you populating the html on the backend or on the frontend? It would be much faster if the tooltips are populated along with the divs and not later

Comment: I've chosen that way because I have many many pages to fill with more than 400 different ingredients. It was to create the pages faster by only entering the ingredient. And if later I want to add something like a link or something else I can do it on the entire website without going through every pages.

Comment: Are those pages not generated dynamically? Are they static? If so, why?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Those pages are generated from a Prestashop, and I add this list of ingredients right after the prestashop template of the product page.

Comment: There are better and more efficient ways of doing this, but since you want to do it on the front end like this, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf2htgke/

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks a lot ! I would be interested by the other way of doing it. (I'm still a beginner) if you have some time.

Comment: @DenisHénon Can you post a snippet of the code that generates the html?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir here is a link to the tpl file : https://jpst.it/2lM3F

Answer (score 1):

In other words: A set of strings that indicate specific ingredients.
If those strings are stored in a simple array in an order related to their so-called `ingredient nr` then you could simply use the `index+1` after identifying which ingredient string is included in the value of the string variable called `ss`.

So first let's create the array we mentioned earlier:

```
const ingredientStrList = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'];
```

Now let's create a dummy `ss` variable with an possible and testable value:

```
const ss = '12test12';
```

Now we need a way to iterate over all strings of the array and check if they are included in the string `ss` and if so return the wanted `index` of that `ingredient string` that matched.

For that, we can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which does the iteration for us and also returns the index if a match was found. But we must tell [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which function it should use to check the ingredient strings against.

Of course we use `ss.includes` for that needed checking function,  ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶b̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶[̶t̶h̶i̶s̶]̶[̶2̶]̶ ̶k̶e̶y̶w̶o̶r̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶n̶a̶l̶l̶y̶.̶
̶S̶o̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶m̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶[̶t̶h̶i̶s̶]̶[̶2̶]̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶e̶d̶.̶ ̶F̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶[̶b̶i̶n̶d̶]̶[̶3̶]̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶

So by using all of those previously mentioned things together we can come up with a function like this:

```
function getIngredientNr(ingredientStrList, text){
  const nr = ingredientStrList.findIndex(e=>text.includes(e))+1;
  return nr || undefined; //returns undefined if no ingredient str matched
}
```

And here is a test for you to run to convince yourself that it works as intended:

```js
function getIngredientNr(ingredientStrList, text){
  const nr = ingredientStrList.findIndex(e=>text.includes(e))+1;
  return nr || undefined;
}
const ingredients = [
  'Citrus Limon Fruit Water',
   'Hamamelis Virginiana Water',
   'Glycerin'
];
document.querySelectorAll('#ingredients > div > span').forEach(s=>{
  const ss = s.parentNode.innerText;
  const ingNr = getIngredientNr(ingredients, ss);
  s.innerText = ingNr 
    ? `this is the number ${ingNr} ingredient` 
    : 'unknown ingredient!';
});
```

```html
<div id="ingredients">
  <div class="tooltiping bio" style="color: black;">Citrus Limon Fruit Water,&nbsp;
    <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltiping bio" style="color: black;"> Hamamelis Virginiana Water,&nbsp;
    <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltiping bio" style="color: black;"> Glycerin,&nbsp;
    <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your code works but this is not exactly what I aimed. I'm sorry it's my fault, I didn't explained very well. This is not about the number of the ingredient it's more about its "translation" as : Citrus Lemon Fruit Water -> It's some water with lemon, Hamamelis Virginiana Water -> its another thing , Glycerin -> again another thing. So it would work with 2 const?

Comment: Is there any way to "link" 2 arrays ? The first Array would contain Ingredients like these:  const ingredients = [
  'Citrus Limon Fruit Water',
   'Hamamelis Virginiana Water',
   'Glycerin'
];  and the second would contain the "translation" of the first one like : const ingredients = [
  'this is pure lemon',
   'this is hamamelis flower extract',
   'this is some Glycerin'
];
and when it find in the html a value contained in the array it show the equivalent (which would be placed at the same index) in the second one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ingredients = [ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3, ingredient4];
let index = 0;
let unknown = false;
for (const ingredient of ingredients) {
  if (ingredient){ console.log(`this is ingredient number ${index + 1}`); unknown = true; break; }
  index++;
}
if (unknown) console.log('unknown');
```

Using for loops and break.

Comment: What if it's an unknown ingredient?

Comment: This approach does not take into account that the original approach, while looping, actually does, for every iteration, test the existence for two specific ingredients via `ss.includes("test1");` and `ss.includes("test2");`. Whether this testing is still an essential part of the OP's story or not has to be clarified before one starts throwing code at the OP.